# Docker/GitLab authentication for docker registry returns 401 error

Tags: docker, authentication, gitlab, docker-registry

I'm trying to configure my docker registry using auth of gitlab (docker).

Doing `docker login registry.website.com` gives me a **401 Unauthorized** error:

```
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://registry.website.com/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
```

In the docker logs I find

```
{ "level":"info","msg":"token signed by untrusted key with ID: \"IWNY:KT2H:YUN5:STQP:22LM:YNIU:RT4T:AZO7:TBVL:ZQ3I:Z4JZ:LA3T\"","time":"2018-12-17T23:36:03.538232467Z" }
{ [...] "level":"warning","msg":"error authorizing context: invalid token","service":"registry","source":"registry","time":"2018-12-17T23:36:03.53860308Z","version":"v2.6.2" }
```

My keys are generated by doing

```
$ sudo openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -subj "/CN=gitlab-issuer" -nodes -x509 -keyout registry-auth.key -out registry-auth.crt
$ sudo chmod 400 registry-auth.key
```

In my debugging attempt I do get different sha256 digest:

```
459b854f47c51bd94e0fd696cc35148cf93065df986abcc368cf13958373d298
459b854f47c51bd94e0fd696cc35148cf93065df986abcc368cf13958373
```

As @VDR has shown this is ok, as the first 30 characters are used. So with that there should not be a problem with the keys. But why do I get the 401 error?

This is how I configured gitlab and the registry:

The configuration of docker gitlab (gitlab.rb) uses the key by

```
gitlab_rails['registry_key_path'] = "/certs/registry-auth.key"
```

Config of registry has

```
auth.token.rootcertbundle: /root/certs/registry-auth.crt
```

*nginx-proxy/vhost.d/docker-registry.conf*

```
proxy_pass                          http://registry.website.com;
proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;   # required for docker client's sake
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr; # pass on real client's IP
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_read_timeout                  900;
```

I don't see what I'm missing here...

Comment: Based on this link: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/8-15-stable/lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb#L35
This hash is supposed to be the most part of the sha256 hex digest of the public key in DER format(registry-auth.pub.der).

Comment: @VDR You are right. This would prove that the key which I'm using are correct, but why do I get the 401 error?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @JulienLachal Yes, nginx reverse proxy

Comment: @JulienLachal I'm using `jwilder/nginx-proxy`.

Comment: Did you find something about it @user3142695 ? I have the exact same problem and have no idea what's going on :'(

Comment: @EricD Unfortunately I'm still facing this issue. Maybe you want to start a bounty on this?

Comment: @EricD Did you have any luck to solve your issue?

Comment: wich os is your machine, windows or linux ?

Comment: @Soleil Linux, ubuntu

Comment: check you clock in your machines, that same in registry and request

Answer (score 1):

If your Gitlab is behind a proxy, you will need to configure the proxy in docker.

To configure docker to use the proxy, put the following in your `~/.docker/config.json` file where your docker is running.

```
{
  "auths" : {

  },
  "proxies":
  {
    "default":
    {
      "httpProxy": "http://myproxy/",
      "httpsProxy": "http://myproxy/"
    }
  }
}
```

If there is anything already in the `"auths": {}` section, you should leave it as is.

Save this file then restart your docker daemon. Once docker is back up, you should be able to run `docker login ...` without issues.

Comment: I do not understand what I have to use for `myproxy`. I'm user the reverse proxy builder/nginx-proxy

Comment: `myproxy` would be the domain of the proxy that your Gitlab is sitting behind.